# Order of partitions for root, home and swap with respect to Windows partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I am installing Ubuntu on the same hard drive as Windows 7.

The partitions of Windows 7 have already occupied the left part of the hard drive. From left to right, the Windows partitions are one partition for Windows booting, one for Windows OS and software installation, and one for data which is planned to mount on Ubuntu.

I was wondering how to arrange the order of partitions of root, home and swap, i.e. which is on the left just besides one Windows partition, which is in the middle and which is on the far right? Is there some consideration regarding about this arrangement?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter where your partitions are. You can have root be on a primary or logical partition. You can have root, home, and boot all smushed together on one partition, or micromanage all your folders to different partitions (you might hit a built-in limit for logical partitions (~59?), and you're only allowed four primary). I think you could even have all your partitions running on a networked file share.

I've always partitioned boot as my first logical partition, because I know I'm only going to give it 100 mB. Then I think about making a swap, and usually decide against it. Next I decide how much space I'll give up to root. Finally, I give home the rest of the space. If I'm not dual booting Windows, root gets to be in a primary partition. Everything else gets logical partitions.

See TLDP for more info:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/intro.html#explanation

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/partition-types.html

Answer (score 2):

The only consideration is that the disk tends to be faster near the start, and slower near the end.  The difference isn't likely anything you will notice though.